# Javascript display same content on each checkbox clicks?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple check boxes and i want them to display the same content when each of them is clicked. Now when I click on one check box, the content appears, but until I unclick it the next checkbox won't display any content. I want the all the contents to be displayed as long as check boxes are clicked. any tip with this.
I tried this:

```
function showTime(days){        
    var showTime = document.getElementById("time_schedules");
    var days = document.getElementById("schedule");
    if (days.checked) {
        showTime.style.display = "Block";
    }
    else{
        showTime.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you put your code in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Need more code to help you, but the name of your parameter is the same at the name of one of your variable. And if you have multiple checkbox you can't give the same ID to all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Insert some class attribute to all your checkboxes so you can select them, then capture the click event, iterate over all checkboxes and perform whatever you need to do (setting label etc).

I recommend using some javascript library such as jquery, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="cb" />
<label for="cb1" class="cblabel">label1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" class="cb" />
<label for="cb2" class="cblabel">label2</label>

$('.cb').bind('click', function() {
    $('.cblabel').each(function(i,v) { v.innerHTML = 'hello'; });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3EMyY/

Comment: Now the check box is showing data on checked, but the data should be displayed as long as the box is checked even if other boxes are cheked. for example when two boxes are checked, two of the data should be dispalyed.